# Don't trigger a layout in webkit could be an optimize option in IE, too?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, optimization, webkit

Recently I read some article about website optimize, one of rules talk about don't trigger layout in weibkit http://gent.ilcore.com/2011/03/how-not-to-trigger-layout-in-webkit.html

I know firefox have the same procedure called reflow, so I think this optimize option could work in firefox.

But this could work in IE? Why? Is all browser engine work the same way?

Answer (score 0):

ie now have a brilliant set of developer tools.The UI Responsiveness panel can be used if you want to profile performance. The method of not triggering a layout DOES work in ie. I borrowed and modified a demo to test although the performance benefits were easy to see without the tools. 
http://codepen.io/tarranjones/full/CqIkF